# Parsing Dynamic Time Format in Go

Tags: go, datetime-parsing

I'm working with an external API that will sometimes shorten the returned timestamp if the last values are zero.

```
layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000"
opened, err := time.Parse(layout, externallyFormattedTimestamp)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("something went wrong parsing the timestamp")
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}
```

If the returned externallyFormattedTimestamp is `2018-11-05T06:19:59.827`, this will parse without issue.

But if the time returned ends with zeros, it'll be shortened like `2018-11-05T06:19:59.8` instead of `2018-11-05T06:19:59.800`, and break. Do I need to manually append zeros to the string before parsing, or is there something I missed built into Go that will handle this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this layout instead: `2006-01-02T15:04:05.999`